# I am installing Oracle 11g 64bit on Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS and the setup shows the following error message on Prerequisite Checks screen:

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, oracle

I am installing Oracle 11g 64bit on Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS and the setup shows the following error message on the Prerequisite Checks screen:

```
This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "make-3.80" is available on the system. (more details)
Expected Value
 : make-3.80
Actual Value
 : missing
```

On the command line when I run sudo apt-get install make I get:

make is already the newest version (4.3-4.1build1).

I tried to purge it by doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge make
```

and trying to install the 3.80 version of make

```
sudo apt-get install make=3.80
```

and I got

```
package make is a virtual package provided by:

  make-guile 4.3-4.1build1 (= 4.3-4.1build1)

You should explicitly select one to install.



E: Version '3.80' for 'make' was not found
```

There are a lot of other dependencies that the setup is not able to find. Why can't install them?

[image: Support image]

Comment: Oracle database strictly depends on exact versions of dependencies. 11g is an ancient version. You would need to read the Oracle 11g system requirements, and install an OS that is equally ancient

Comment: So is it necessary to install an old version of Ubuntu? Are you confirming? I've read the requirements before, but I didn't catch anything about the Ubuntu version.
thanks for your response @DanielT

Comment: Oracle 11g is not supported on Ubuntu: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24684_01/doc/install.11203/e24322/pre_install.htm Choose a supported OS

Comment: @DanielT I am aware of this and I have read that Ubuntu operating systems or derivatives are not on the list of operating systems supported by the Oracle Database. I only want to use it for development at most and not as a database on a production server.

Comment: Oracle seems to insist on their exact library versions. If you want to use Ubuntu without an Oracle OS VM for development, you could try finding a Docker container with the required libraries, or even a completely prebuilt Docker container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986430/10477326

Comment: Thank you @DanielT Im gonna take a look